# Exception Handling with a WebClient object

Tags: .net, f#

I've written a function to initiate a download given an url and WebClient object in F#. However, when I write my try .. with statement is gives me the error "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression."

```
let urlDownload(url:string, webClient:WebClient) = 
async {
    try 
        let uri = new Uri(url)
        /// References for progress queries
        let contentLength = ref 0L
        let bytesReceived = ref 0L
        /// Updates progress statistics as progress is made
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged.Add(
            fun args ->
                if !contentLength = 0L && webClient.ResponseHeaders.Get "Content-Length" <> null then
                    contentLength := webClient.ResponseHeaders.Get "Content-Length" |> Int64.Parse
                bytesReceived := !bytesReceived + args.BytesReceived
        )
        let! html = webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)
    with
        | :? UriFormatException -> printfn "Invalid URL"
 }
```

It's based off of the code from the msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx)

What's really strange is that if I put 'printfn ""' before the with block the project compiles without errors. However, when I run it, it then throws a UriFormatException which is suppose to be caught by the with block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian says, the issue is that you're ending a block (the body of the try) with `let!`, but it never makes sense to end an expression with a binding.  Presumably, you want your function to actually return the HTML, so you should do:

```
let! html = webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)
return html
```

or equivalently, just `return! webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)`.

Answer (score 1):

> What's really strange is that if I put
>   'printfn ""' before the with block the
>   project compiles without errors.

This is expected.  A `let!` can't be the last line of an `async` block, just like a `let` can't be the last line of a normal block.  (Recall that

```
let x = 42
blah(x)
```

is 'shorthand' for the expression

```
let x = 42 in blah(x)
```

)

I think I don't believe you regarding the `UriFormatException`.  :)